# Struct sizeof doesn't compile

Tags: c++, struct, typedef, sizeof

i tried to create two struct one is the main one and he has pointer to the second struct.
when i tries to use sizeof in the main it's says "unable to open the file C:/..."

```
typedef struct virus {
    int time;
    zol* x;
};

typedef struct zol {
    int y;
};

void main()
{
    printf("%d", (int)sizeof(virus));
}
```

Comment: "Unable to open the file" is a problem with your compilation process, not your code.

Comment: There are many things wrong with the above code (like the `typedef`s, the `void` return type of `main()`), but your `sizeof(virus)` is actually fine.

Comment: 1) Those `typedef`'s are both wrong and unnecessary in C++. 2) `zol* x;` But `zol` has not been declared at this point, yet.

Comment: Is this really a C++? Code looks like pure C (ignoring errors common for C and C++).

Comment: @MarekR As C, code would not compile.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/3hdjYq

Comment: @MarekR, Okay, but when you fixed the errors, it started compiling in C++ as well.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes in original code there are some problems which in C++ mode lead only to warnings. Still this (original) code doesn't compile in C++ mode: https://godbolt.org/z/68Y3TW

Comment: @MarekR I made no comment about compile-ability in C++. As C, OP's code errors with `error: 'virus' undeclared (first use in this function) printf("%d", (int)sizeof(virus));` so is not C code as suggested by [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229493/struct-sizeof-doesnt-compile#comment117091086_66229493).

Answer (score 2):

The error message quoted is (presumably) a consequence of the compilation errors in your code. Next time you post about an error, post the **first** error message not the last.

Here's the code corrected. The main problem with your code was the fact that you used `zol` before you have defined it, it should be the other way around. There's also a missing header file for `printf` and the typedefs are wrong.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct zol {
    int y;
};

struct virus {
    int time;
    zol* x;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(virus));
}
```

Comment: I'd add `#include <cstdio>` and perhaps make it `std::printf("%zu", sizeof(virus));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Done.